# Change the color of the number of suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, design, suggested-edits, review-page

The *2* on the review page is hardly visible. Even though a disabled/grayed out look might be desired (because I couldn't actually review these suggested edits), this is just illegible:

[image: illegible number 2]

(Using Safari 5.1.2 on Windows 7)

Related question on gaming.sx: [Hot brown on brown action in /review](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1809/hot-brown-on-brown-action-in-review)